# Can not make sure that code snippet result is updated

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

When I write code in a code snippet I use the "RUN" button many times to check the current state of my code, but there is no indication to make sure if the result is changed so I click the <kbd>Run</kbd> button 2-3 times every time!

I suggest a Running/Waiting icon or a simple blink or something similar to indicate that the result is being updated.

Comment: I encounter this too, it can be unintuitive when you press the "Run" button and you don't see any visual change at all, especially when one's connection isn't perfect. Perhaps blank out the HTML (including any console messages) *when the **Run** button is pressed*, rather than when the `stacksnippets.net/js` response comes back. (This would be accomplishable rather easily with a userscript)

Comment: Add code that changes on every run. Something like `console.log(Date.now())` might be enough...

Comment: For me pressing the RUN button 3 times is easier than a short line of code :) @HereticMonkey

Answer (score -5):

Here's a quick little userscript that will make the result iframe invisible until the iframe loads with the response from stacksnippets.net, which should make it quite clear when the snippet is being reloaded.

edit: made snippets in the page proper behave the same way, rather than just changing the iframe in the snippet interface

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Stack Snippet Status Indicator
// @description  Blanks out the snippet result's iframe while it's loading
// @author       CertainPerformance
// @version      1.1
// @match        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

const fixIframe = (iframe) => {
  iframe.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  iframe.addEventListener(
    'load',
    () => {
      iframe.style.removeProperty('visibility');
    },
    { once: true }
  );
};

document.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  // While editing a snippet in the snippet interface,
  // match the blue "Run" button or its descendant:
  if (target.matches('#snpte-button-run, #snpte-button-run *')) {
    const iframe = document.querySelector('#snpte-box-edit-result');
    fixIframe(iframe);
  }
  // Match the blue "Run" button outside the snippet interface:
  else if (target.matches('.snippet-ctas button:not(.hideResults), .snippet-ctas button:not(.hideResults) *')) {
    const iframe = target.closest('.snippet-result').querySelector('iframe');
    fixIframe(iframe);
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused, should I not have posted my solution to the problem? Did I do something wrong?